# How to refer to an object's "Owner" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, inheritance, attributes, hierarchy

"Owner" is probably not the right term for this but I don't know what is so it's making the search very difficult.

I'm making a card game, and each player can have multiple hands of cards.

I have a "Player," "Hand," and "Card" classes.

```
player1 = Player.new 
hand1 = Hand.new # => A new hand of two random cards

player1.hands.push(hand1)

#Now player1 has one hand with two cards in it.
```

Is there an attribute or method I can call on hand1 that will refer to its "owner", player1?

I'm expecting something like

```
hand1.owner

=> #<Player:0x007fb6ae05b448
# @behavior=:human,
# @hands=[#<Hand:0x007fb6ad8653b0 @cards=[{:A,:spades},{:Q,:hearts}]>],
# @money=800,
# @name="Dougie Jones">
```

Comment: I know this may be just an example, but if you need to query hands to determine their player, I'd say you've modeled something wrong.

Comment: I am going to have to agree with @MarkThomas on this one. Why does the `Hand` need to know its `Player`? Let's assume we are playing "Go Fish"... You would ask the `Player` about a `Card` in their `Hand` not ask the `Hand` about the `Player`. A `Hand` should only know about the `Card`s and a `Player` should know about the `Hand` and through the `Hand` know about the `Card`s

Comment: It's a blackjack game and sometimes you need to split a hand into two hands, up to a total of four. I found it easier to have each hand "play" itself and have all player and AI decisions take place in the Hand class. I didn't run into trouble until I realized that doubling and splitting required the hand to know whether its player had enough money. I probably would structure it differently now, especially since I still have a lot of gameplay methods in the Player class anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. An object doesn't know where you keep it. You may keep it in many different places, who is going to be the owner then? You need to set relationships manually or consider changing design.

Consider this:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :hands

  def initialize
    @hands = []
  end

  def add_hand(hand)
    hand.player = self
    @hands << hand
  end
end

class Hand
  attr_accessor :player
end

player = Player.new
hand = Hand.new
player.add_hand(hand)
puts hand.player #=> #<Player:0x000000017b2978>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Adding the .player attribute to from the Player class' new_hand method is so much simpler than the workaround I found, which was to pass the player's unique identifier into the new_hand method as an additional parameter, and then turning it into an attribute within the Hand class' initializer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can cross-reference objects with attributes. (every `Hand` object can reference a specific `Player` object)

For example, you can add an attribute to your `Hand` model:

```
class Hand
  attr_accessor :player
end
```

Then when you create a new `Hand`, you can set the `player`:

```
player1 = Player.new
hand1 = Hand.new
hand1.player = player1
```

This is essentially how [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) work.

Comment: A year later I'm looking over my post history and see your comment. Man, I was completely not at all ready to hear about ActiveRecord stuff back then. I'd definitely approach this problem differently now!